# Control Volume Analysis - enthalpy substituted for internal energy?

Tags: thermodynamics

In the process of deriving stagnation / total enthalpy, *Fundamentals of Gas Dynamics* (Zucker & Biblarz) claim that for any locations $a$ and $b$,

$$h_a + \frac{V_a^2}{g_c} + \frac{g}{g_c}z_a + q = h_b + \frac{V_b^2}{g_c} + \frac{g}{g_c}z_b + w_s$$

This appears to come from the 1st law of thermodynamics $q = w +\Delta e$, where $e = u + \frac{V^2}{g_c} + \frac{g}{g_c}z$. However, I am not sure why enthalpy $h$ is substituted for internal energy $u$? I thought that $h = u + pv$, and I don't think $\Delta(pv)=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shaft work is not the total work that is done by the fluid within the control volume.  In the control volume derivation, part of the work goes into pushing fluid into and out of the control volume.  This $\Delta (pv)$ portion of the work is separated out and lumped together with the internal energy terms to give the enthalpy terms.

Comment: Sorry, 1 more question: q = w_s + pv + ∆e, so e_a + q = e_b + pv + w_s. I can see where the h on the right side comes from now, but what about the left? You seem to suggest that ∆pv is being taken out from work, not just pv?

Comment: pv work is associated with pushing fluid into the control volume at the entrance, and additional pv work is associated with pushing fluid out of the control volume at the exit.